# How to fetch each array element in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to fetch each element of array in foreach loop.

Here in my code my array is displayed, I want to fetch this array element in if condition.

```
   if (!empty($data[5])) {
    $selectsql = "select value_id from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery where entity_id = '".$entity_id."'"; 
            $selectsqlresult = $connection->query($selectsql);
            $resultquery  = $selectsqlresult->fetchAll(); 
    print_r($resultquery);

        if(!empty($resultquery['value_id']))
        {
            $imgpos = 2;
            foreach($resultquery as $value)
            {
                $updatequery = "update catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value set position = '".$imgpos."' where value_id = '".$value."' limit 1";
                //$connection->query($updatequery);
                echo $updatequery . "\n";
                echo "Images Position - " . $imgpos ."\n\n";    $imgpos++;  
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to increase images position by 1 as per the array element.
Image position `$imgpos` is used in update query.

Please provide some guidance.

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. Do you want to increment the current "position" of each row, or renumber everything starting from 0?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the key value in the foreach statement to get a incremented value:

```
if(!empty($resultquery['value_id']))
{

            foreach($resultquery as $imgpos => $value)
            {
                $updatequery = "update catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value set position = '".$imgpos."' where value_id = '".$value."' limit 1";
                //$connection->query($updatequery);
                echo $updatequery . "\n";
                echo "Images Position - " . $imgpos ."\n\n";    $imgpos++;  
            }
}
```

Comment: Heads up - there's a typo in the foreach (`$impos => $value` should be `$imgpos => $value`)